# Certificate not trusted error while accessing WCF with SSL security in IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, ssl, https

I am facing the following issue.

1 - I have deployed WCF service with SSL enabled on remote IIS machine and trying to use it from my web client.The problem is my browser is not allowing this service to be called.Before using my web client i have to hit the service url from my browser directly and then allow the certificate.

2- Got suggestion from somewhere to export the certificate on the machine where WCF is deployed and include that certificate file in Trusted certificates group on my machine.After I did that I got same problem when tried to access web service from web client.So I hit the service url from browser and got the same page which needs me to trust the certificate with a different message that "You attempted to reach 111.121.196.226(ip address of the WCF machine), but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as "WMSvc-domain" where "WMSvc-domain" is the value of "**Issued To**" field in the certificate.

I hope I have made myself clear.Waiting for suggestions.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WMSvc-machinename is the IIS Windows Management Service which runs by default on 8172/tcp and is used for remotely managing iis. When installed the default is to create a self-signed certificate.  That wouldn't trusted.  It could be replaced with a "proper" CA signed cert through the Management Service icon in IIS Manager.